# Extract all values from a PostgreSQL JSON array given a key

Tags: json, postgresql

How exctract from json in postgres

```json
[{"val":"2","dsk:"one"},{"val":"2","dsk":"two"},{"val":"3","dsk":"three"}]
```

where dsk values

It return null values

```
SELECT '[{"val":"2","dsk:"one"},{"val":"2","dsk":"two"},{"val":"3","dsk":"three"}]'::json->'dsk'
```

Comment: So what is the output you expect? Three rows?

Comment: Because it's an array; you could get a single element with something like this `SELECT '[{"val":"2","dsk:"one"},{"val":"2","dsk":"two"},{"val":"3","dsk":"three"}]'::json->0->'dsk'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `jsonb_path_query_array` function and extract the entire value from the array

```
select jsonb_path_query_array('[{"val":"2","dsk":"one"},{"val":"2","dsk":"two"},{"val":"3","dsk":"three"}]','$[*].dsk')
```

Demo in [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d85609aff18eed8ca72c0dea2c273dee)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you cannot use your approach because it is an array, but you can try a different one with a json function:

```
WITH data
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM json_array_elements('[{"val":"2","dsk":"one"},{"val":"2","dsk":"two"},{"val":"3","dsk":"three"}]'::json)
    )
SELECT value->'dsk'
FROM data
```